# Can I have vertically aligned subscript and superscript with Word or LibreOffice?

Tags: alignment, microsoft-word, latex, mathematics, libre-office

The *[Arithmetical Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy)* is an example where one in mathematics uses aligned subscripts and superscripts. When writing in Latex I e.g. write $\Pi^1_1$ to talk about a certain class of formulas. How can I achieve this in Word or LibreOffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's certainly possible with LibreOffice.

In LibreOffice Writer, click `Insert` > `Object` > `Formula`

In the window that opens at the bottom type in the formula as follows

```
%PI^1_1
```

Here's a screen shot
[image: Screen shot of inserting Formula]

LibreOffice also comes with a separate Math application, which can also be used to create formulas.  There's further documentation here on the using formulas in Math in LibreOffice https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/3/37/MG40-MathGuide.pdf

Comment: Many thanks for this! It is unfortunate that the insertion box of Libreoffice Writer makes one control of the surrounding texts so that the hyphen does not olace well well such as in writing $\Pi^1_1$-comprehension in Latex.

Comment: You can put the surrounding text in a text box if you want to move it around.